# How to keep password box in backgroundworker(c#)

Tags: c#, windows

I am creating one folder lock application in **c#** .I have created one form and one background worker. I need to keep a **textbox** in **backgroundworker** to enter password .some one help me with that pls.. thanks in advance.
I have already tried with input box but that isn't accepting password char.
here is my **inputbox** code:

```
 pwrd = Interaction.InputBox("Please Enter Password", "Password Required", "", btnEncrypt.Location.X, btnEncrypt.Location.Y);
```

Comment: What does the background worker do? what functionality you want to implement? What is the use of password? When you want user to see that?

Comment: Backgroundworker accepts the password from user and has  to do encrypt or decrypt function.I have written those function but now I wanna implement a textbox in backgroundworker instead of inputbox.

Comment: You need to have some Form with a textbox and a button which you show from the backgroundworker and accept password and do encrypt/decrypt. You can't just how textbox without putting it in a form. Showing some code of background worker and which code you want to show the textbox would help.

Comment: Thankyou. but, If thats the case from as of now I have  2 main function Encrypt() and decrypt(). which I call from backgroundworker functions. Now Iam confused like after creating a new form once the user enters the password and clicked submit which method should be called inside that button_click function?